# Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type:

Tags: java

There was error occurred in Line 14.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - Erroneous sym type:

Hard to find solution.

```
package example;

public class Num
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
    String s = "42";
        try 
        {
            s = s.concat(".5"); 
            double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
            s = Double.toString(d);
            int x = (int) Math.ceil(Double.valueOf(s).doubleValue()); //Line 14
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiles and runs perfectly on my computer, with the output 43

Comment: I think it is problem on my Netbeans IDE

Comment: @Dissanayake Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The code you provided runs fine on my computer.

I'm guessing you are using Netbeans and may be affected by a bug.
Try this:

> Open the project properties, select the Build-Compiling, uncheck "Compile on save" and rerun the application. This will make sure all your source code becomes recompiled before running it.

Link:  https://forums.netbeans.org/topic43241.html

Comment: Yeah. It is problem with my netbeans IDE. I have tried by changing project properties but not compiled. Then I move to the eclips instead

Comment: I just had this issue on NetBeans 11.2 and this answer solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This is a common issue which I get while working. What I do is clean and build the project. It solves the problem.

> **Right Click on the project name >> Clean and build**

Comment: In my case the i got the same error when i renamed a method in repository and forgot to rename the call to the same method in ServiceImpl.  Clean build pointed me to the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Download/install JDK major version number the same as NetBeans.**

i.e.  If You have NetBeans 9 version, but your JDK is version 10,then try use NetBeans 10 version... or download/install JDK 9 (the same as NetBeans).

**Create new java platform for new jdk installation.**

Open netbeans menubar->tools->Java Platforms->Add Platform
Specify the folder that contains the Java platform as well as the sources and Javadoc needed for debugging.

**Set new java platform to your project**

Right click on project ->properties->Libraries->Java Platform->select the jdk version that  same as NetBeans

**Select source format of your project**

Right click on project ->properties->Sources->Sources/binary format->select the jdk version that  same as NetBeans.

If it still gives errors like,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:1)
C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\dev\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\dev\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

do as "sinclair" has mentioned above.
Open the project properties, select the Build-Compiling, uncheck "Compile on save" and rerun the application. This will make sure all your source code becomes recompiled before running it.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error after I'd changed the type of a function parameter and it was the calling page that was in error - but I didn't see this until a magical **Clean and Build** pointed me to the actual issue!

Answer (score -1):

I got this error message because I copied and pasted code without including the package name. I added the package name and it was fixed.

Answer (score -2):

in my case

i have solved using import with package name and class name

like this import package.class1;

Answer (score -2):

Please uncheck "Compile on save"

[image: attention to the pic]