# Problem in running java code in netbeans ide

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-10

I am using netbeans ide 10.0
I am not able to run even a single code.
please help

i have tried to change java version

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package helloworld;

/**
 *
 * @author admin1
 */
public class HelloWorld {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

i am getting this output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Null ctor sym type: RuntimeException(java.lang.String)
    at helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:1)
/home/admin1/.cache/netbeans/10.0/executor-snippets/run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/admin1/.cache/netbeans/10.0/executor-snippets/run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35114066/5156075

Comment: I hv tried all the things in given link....still not working

Comment: The latest available download is NetBeans IDE 8.0.2. Are you sure you are install Netbeans?

Comment: https://netbeans.apache.org/download/     I downloaded from this link

Comment: hmm..I have no idea on that, as I never use apache netbeans before.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?[Like this?](https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/uncompilable-source-code-exception-in-netbeans/) Also Netbeans re-branded to apache netbeans for all versions past 8. Currently the highest is 11

Comment: i actually now changed and started working on eclipse IDE and it is running fine. Is it problem of Netbeans bath or something