# I want to find even and odd number using two thread evenCount and oddCount

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */



class evenCount extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        for(int i = 2; i >=20; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}

class oddCount extends Thread {
    
    public void run(){
    for(int i = 21; i>=31; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(700);
        }
        
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    }
}

class mainThread{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        evenCount even = new evenCount();
        oddCount odd  = new oddCount();
        
        even.run();
        odd.run();
    }
}
```

```````````````````Description````````````````````````

I want to find even and odd numbers but the output show me like this :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Thread.
at evenCount.(Thread.java:16)
at mainThread.main(Thread.java:56)
/Users/user/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Sometimes it shows build successfull but doesnt show the result(when i use Runnable)

Comment: See [java - Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114025/uncompilable-source-code-erroneous-sym-type)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show any output, because your for loop condition is wrong.

`for(int i = 2; i >=20; i++)`
and
 `for(int i = 21; i>=31; i++)`

both for-loop never get through.

It should be **i<=20** and **i<=31**

At least with above change, you will get output.