# catching negative and letter input exception from driver class

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a try-catch block to catch negative and characters as a salary input.

I've tried t-c block in base class, driver class, sub class, but can't get it to catch this erroneous input.

I've tried using a double variable that makes sure the "salary/earnings" input is actually erroneous.

Also when printing e1 instance,  the first string value "firstName" always prints null.  Why is this, went through it with the debugger, and it reads the value correctly but doesn't print it.

I would appreciate your help.

//FullTimeInstructor.java

```
package Employee;

public class FullTimeInstructor extends Employee {
private double weeklySalary;

public FullTimeInstructor(String firstName, String lastName, String taxFileNumber, double weeklySalary) {
    super(firstName, lastName, taxFileNumber);
    this.weeklySalary = weeklySalary;
            if (weeklySalary < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The salary cannot be a negative or a letter");
    } else if (weeklySalary != Double.NaN) 

/*tried this also... 
If (((Object)weeklySalary).getClass().getName()!="java.lang.Double")*/

{
        
throw new InputMismatchException("The salary cannot be a letter");

    }

}

public double getWeeklySalary() {
    return weeklySalary;
}

public void setWeeklySalary(double weeklySalary) {
    this.weeklySalary = weeklySalary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + taxFileNumber + " " + weeklySalary + " " + 
Earnings();
}
public double Earnings(){
    return weeklySalary;
}
}
```

//employee.java

```
package Employee;

abstract class Employee {

public String firstName;
public String lastName;

public String taxFileNumber;

public Employee(String firstName, String lastName,String taxFileNumber) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.taxFileNumber = taxFileNumber;
  }

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getTaxFileNumber() {
    return taxFileNumber;
}

public void setTaxFileNumber(String taxFileNumber) {
    this.taxFileNumber = taxFileNumber;
}


public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + taxFileNumber;
}

public abstract double Earnings();
}
```

//EarningsTesting.java

```
package Employee;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class EarningsTesting {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
   
       
   try {

        FullTimeInstructor e1 = new FullTimeInstructor("Jane", "Smythe", "456DEF", 29000);
        System.out.println(e1);
        FullTimeInstructor e2 = new FullTimeInstructor("Janet", "Smith", "987TYR", 20000);
        System.out.println(e2);
        PartTimeInstructor e3 = new PartTimeInstructor("Alan", "Peters", "345AER", 25.0, 5.0, 20.0, 10.0);
        System.out.println(e3);
        PartTimeInstructor e4 = new PartTimeInstructor("Boris", "Johnson", "765PER", 25.0, 7.0, 20.0, 11.0);
        System.out.println(e4);
        SessionalInstructor e5 = new SessionalInstructor("Jeff", "Leyland", "555POI", 20.0, 5.0);
        System.out.println(e5);
        SessionalInstructor e6 = new SessionalInstructor("Jasmine", "Turner", "856YTE", 20.0, 6.0);
        System.out.println(e6);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For your second problem, there is a typo in your Employee constructor. Line 'this.lastName = firstName;' should be 'this.firstName = firstName;'

Comment: The first name problem is because the base-class constructor is wrong `this.lastName = firstName;` should be `this.firstName = firstName;`

Comment: You're not doing anything with your `if` statements? You check for the condition, but then close with a `;` right away so even when the condition is true it does nothing.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with this code `if (this.weeklySalary < 0);` - This line doesn't do anything.  Perhaps you want to **throw** an exception here to handle the case were the input is negative?  And then catch it in your test harness?

Answer (score 6):

Try - catch structure is used to capture an exception that has been thrown in the code. It you want to generate an exception, throw an Exception instead in the contructor:

```
if (weeklySalary < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The salary of "+ e1.getName() +" is negative");
}
```

Then you can catch it with a try - catch block to act on it (as an example):

```
try {
    FullTimeInstructor e1 = new FullTimeInstructor(someName, otherName, someId, negativeSalary);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // do something here with the invalid arguments
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has sorted out my problem, second exception to catch is char/non-double, however, this is throwing runtime time exception "Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: <any>".  I've amended my code to show what I am doing.

Comment: There is no need for checking types in this case.
Java is a typed language, as long as you don't use casting, the types of the input should respect the function declared type (double). but if you do use casting, then you can more easily check types using instanceof.

regarding your compilation exception that should be the subject of another question. 
But it looks like an editor related issue (googled your exception and found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114025/uncompilable-source-code-erroneous-sym-type)

Answer (score 1):

you need to think clearly as below:

- when you construct an employee object, do you want it to be successfully constructed even the weeklySalary is negative ? if not, you should throw an exception in constructor method when it's negative.
- when you invoke the Earnings method, do you expect this method to validate the weeklySalary? if so, you should validate in the Earnings method and throw exception when it's negative.